# Function to search for string in array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

I am trying to write a function that searches for the unique part(maximum two characters) of a string in an array of strings. Although `strstr` and `strchr` are not working and crash my program for some reason. So I have resorted to trying to create something that resembles their function.

My question is this:
Why is strstr not working (something like `strstr(lex[j],word)`) and what am I doing wrong here?

Here is the code for the function that searches for two unique characters within an array of strings :

```
void convert(char word[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0 ; i <= strlen(word) ; i++)
    {
        if(word[i] >= 65 && word[i] <= 90)
        {
            word[i] = word[i]+32;
        }
    }
}


int  twochar(char lex[50][50],char word[], int size,char temp[3])
{
    int i,j,k,count,totlen;
    convert(word);

    for (i = 0 ; i < strlen(word) - 1 ; i++)
    {
        count = 0;
        totlen = 0;
        for(j = 0; j<size; j++)
        {
            convert(lex[j]);
            totlen += strlen(lex[j]) - 1;
            for(k = 0 ; k < strlen(lex[j]) - 1 ; k++)
            {
                if (word[i] != lex[j][k] || word[i+1] != lex[j][k + 1])
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(count =  = totlen)
        {
            temp[0] = word[i];
            temp[1] = word[i+1];
        }
    }
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char lex[50][50] =  {"word1","word2","word3","word4" }, word[] = "test";
    char p[3];

    twochar(lex,word,4,p);
    printf("%c%c\n",p[0],p[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This `strlen(lex[j])-1` is a receipe for desaster. Imagine what happens if `lex[j]` is an emtpy "string" with the length of `0`. Hint: Check the type `strlen()` returns.

Comment: I deleted my comment which said you do not terminate `temp[]` by using `temp[2]='\0'` because I noticed you never use `temp` or `p` as a string, only as a plain array.

Comment: well i know it's not the best solution, but what could be an alternative?

Comment: consistent indentation, say 4 spaces after every opening brace and un-indent before every closing brace would make the code much easier for humans to read/understand

Comment: Using `strlen()` like that in a `for` loop, indicates a lack of understanding how strings work in c. You need to read about strings in c, what they are, and how `str*()` functions work.

Comment: Run your code in a debugger, trace through it and inspect the relevant values. To learn how to do this you might like to read here: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Two remarks about `convert()`. First the loop is one too short: it should be `i < strlen(word)`. Second, it would be simpler to use `tolower()` to convert to lower case with `word[i] = tolower(word[i]);`

Comment: @WeatherVane yes i know but this was part of an exercise and i had to do it that way.

Comment: In that case the code would be clearer as `if(word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z')`

Comment: Perhaps you should have posted the code showing how `strstr()` and `strchr()` crash your program.

Comment: @WeatherVane the program crashes this way too but i can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line:

```
for(k=0;k<strlen(lex[j])-1;k++)
```

is the problem.

```
strlen(lex[0]) is 0
strlen(lex[0])-1 is -1 (0xFFFFFFFF in a 32 bit system)
k starts at 0 and is incremented until it is equal to 0xFFFFFFFF
```

of course, k exceeds the bounds of lex[0] when k = 50.

the result is undefined behaviour which leads to the seg fault event

To determine all the above, I compiled/linked the program via gcc, with the -ggdb parameter.

then I ran the program via 'gdb theprogram'

```
within gdb I entered
br main <-- break point set
run
c <-- continue
the program then crashed with a seg fault event
then I entered
bt  <-- back trace
the bt showed me this line: 'if(word[i]!=lex[j][k] || word[i+1]!=lex[j] [k+1])'
Then I entered
p k <-- print variable k
=6832   (which is WAY out of bounds)

then I entered
run
y
br theprogram.c:41    (the line number from above) <-- set another break epoint
c
the program stopped at line 41
p j
=0  ( this was the gdb response )
p k 
= 0
p i
= 0

a little thinking, 
stepping though that inner loop using 'n' <-- next
and playing on gdb 
indicated that the problem was in line 42
and resulted in revealing the root of the problem
```

Comment: BTW: the compiler warnings can be eliminated by declaring certain of the loop variables as 'size_t' rather than 'int'